# IF statement between two column values

Tags: php, if-statement

at the moment i'm able to set the background color of a column depending of it's value.

Here is the function for the background-color:

```
function bgcolor($field,$value)
{
    if($field=="column1")
    {
        if($value==5)
        {
            $bgcolor=green;
        }
        else
        {
            $bgcolor="";
        }
    }
    return $bgcolor;
}
```

For the Output I'm using a Table which uses the function to highlight the specific cell

```
for ($cell=0; $cell<mysql_num_rows($result);$cell++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    for ($j=0;$j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        $fieldname=mysql_field_name($result, $j);
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"".bgcolor($fieldname, $row[$j])."\">.row[$j]."</td>";
    }
}
```

It works fine, but how can i compare the values from two different columns?

Comment: What fields are you looking for to compare? What does return `var_dump( $row );`?

Comment: I`d like to compare if the value of column1 is smaller than the value of column2. For example column_value1=5 < column_value2=10 => TRUE;
$row[$j] returns the all the values of a specific column depending of it`s fieldname. For example Column:TestNumbers -> values 1,4,5,7,8 ...